# MacBook Pro (with DVI) to HDMI, including audio - possible?

Tags: video, audio, macbook, hdmi, dvi

I have a MacBook Pro with DVI.  I'd like to hook it up to my living room TV for movies and such but I want to keep it out of the way.

I already have HDMI cables run to the basement where I have a cable box.

Is there something I could you to connect the MBP video and audio to HDMI so I only need the one cable to the TV?

I'm looking for a quality picture but I don't want to spend a ton of $.

I've googled a bit, but I'm looking for some recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get both the audio and video into one signal will require circuitry.

I had a friend in your situation, except he had a newer MBP that has Mini DisplayPort.  He ended up going with [this](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5969&seq=1&format=2) from MonoPrice.  He has excellent results with it.

I don't see the same for DVI+Audio to HDMI, however, or they are much more expensive, e.g. [here](http://www.sharbor.com/products/GEFN9100022.html).

[This](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011405&p_id=5369&seq=1&format=2) however looks promising for you - you would need a TOSLink miniplug adapter to get digital audio out of the MBP's 1/8 stereo jack.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some way to 'merge' the two signals into one cable, whatever the option you choose.

I think the cable from MonoPrice, if available for (mini-)DVI, would be the most elegant solution. It certainly seems the most hassle-free one.